# How to bind handler and make it more flexiable?

Tags: javascript, angular

There is a service that returns menu items:

```
 getAdminMenuItems() {
    return [
      {
        label: 'Задачи',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Создать задачу',
            command: () => this.createTask(),
          },
          { label: 'Список задач', command: () => this.showTasks() },
        ],
      }];
}
```

Problem is I want to reuse this menu in different components with differ handler functions. How to pass handler outside instead `this.showTasks()` and `this.createTask()`? Now code abode is located in component where there are handler functions.

Using in component:

```
   this.menuItems = this.headerService.getMenuItems();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass handlers as parameters to the `getAdminMenuItems()` function.

```
getAdminMenuItems(createTaskHandler, showTasksHandler) {
  return [
    {
      label: 'Задачи',
      items: [
        {
          label: 'Создать задачу',
          command: createTaskHandler,
        },
        { label: 'Список задач', command: showTasksHandler },
      ],
    }
  ];
}
```